# Branch.io did not pass the universal link query params to redirect url with $uri_redirect_mode = 2

Tags: ios, deep-linking, branch.io

Let's say I have the following universal link:

```
https://myapp.test-app.link/yXDv3WQKOA?$uri_redirect_mode=2&product_id=1
```

as I captured the response of the above request, I can see branch.io will trigger the deep link with the default value of $deeplink_path (from: https://docs.branch.io/links/integrate/#deep-linking)

```
window.top.location = validateProtocol("myapp://open?link_click_id=71978436528162224363");
```

my workaround is to override $deeplink_path and duplicate my query params with urlencode, such that:

```
https://myapp.test-app.link/yXDv3WQKOA?$uri_redirect_mode=2&product_id=1&$deeplink_path=open%3Fproduct_id%3D1
```

then it can trigger the deep link with query params:

```
window.top.location = validateProtocol("myapp://open?product_id=1&link_click_id=71978436528162224363")
```

My workaround works but it looks bad as I have to duplicate the query params, is there any settings on branch.io that I can pass the query params from the universal link to my deep link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach seems to be correct. However, if you want to globally open the app using $uri_redirect_mode=2 then you can set URI Scheme Deep Link Mode as Aggressive Mode in your link settings.

[image]

Recommended URI Scheme Deep Link Mode: Intelligent.

This selector allows you to control how and when Branch uses URI schemes to open your app when Universal Links and Android App Links fail. See browser specifics in the docs [here](https://docs.branch.io/links/integrate/#expected-link-behavior).

- Conservative mode will never use URI schemes if there is a risk of error messages.
- Intelligent mode is recommended, and uses Branch data to safely use URI schemes everywhere, with the slight risk of error messages in certain browsers if the app is uninstalled.
- Aggressive will force URI schemes everywhere, causing users without the app to see error messages in some browsers.

If you're creating a link by appending query parameters, just append the control parameters to the URL. Please make sure to URL encode everything, lest the link will break.

Refer to this documentation for more details:
https://docs.branch.io/deep-linking/routing/#option-2-let-branch-use-your-existing-deep-link-routing

In case you have more doubts, please write to support@branch.io.